# Core Data iOS - NSInvalidArgumentException +entityForName: nil

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a little confusing problem with my iPhone project and I don't know how to solve it. When I run app and click on table view "Prijmy" then app will terminate with:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Transakcie''**

For better understanding and solving problem I uploaded my whole [project on Dropbox.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ch15eyzq6b8v952/kocourProject.zip)

Thx very much. :)

Comment: Can you post the line of code that throws the exception?  It appears that you must be calling something like `[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transakcle" inManagedObjectContext:yourContext]` with a `nil` context.  (Hence the exception description _"nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter"_)

Comment: when app terminates, this line of code is highlighted in Xcode: `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transakcie" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];`

Comment: Then `self.managedObjectContext` is `nil`.  You'll have to find where the context should be set.

Comment: Can you please check my project which I uploaded? Im trying to identify where the problem is, but with no success yet :( Im starting to be desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem - the managed object context never gets set on `PrijmyViewController`.

There are two ways to solve this.

(1) The easiest way is to add the following to `awakeFromNib` in `PrijmyViewController`

```
AppDelegate *appController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = appController.managedObjectContext;
```

This is not the cleanest design, because all of your view controllers in the storyboard will have to "reach into" the application's delegate to get the managed object context.  Possibly you'll need to do this on all of your other controllers that ultimately need a managed object context...

(2) Alternatively you could subclass the tab bar controller and use its `prepareForSegue` on the embed segues to  inject the managed object context downstream. In my opinion that's the cleaner solution from a design perspective.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But now my app is terminating in the same table view with `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'.` ? any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialised your appdelegate instance of coredata in your viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    appDelegate=[AppDelegate sharedDelegate];
}
```

i think it solve your problem its worked for me.